# What is the reason for the error 'OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory' in ncpol2sdpa python tool?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using the tool [ncpol2sdpa](http://peterwittek.github.io/ncpol2sdpa/) for semi definite program ( SDP ). I tried few examples mentioned in the link but all of them give the same error due to the final command `solve_sdp(sdpRelaxation)` which I suppose runs the SDP optimization on the concerned constraints. The error I get is

```
Calculating block structure...
Estimated number of SDP variables: 15
Generating moment matrix...
Reduced number of SDP variables: 11 (done: 93%)
Processing 8/10 constraints...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test2.py", line 56, in <module>
print(solve_sdp(sdpRelaxation))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ncpol2sdpa/solver_common.py", line 29, in solve_sdp
return solve_with_sdpa(sdpRelaxation, solverparameters)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ncpol2sdpa/sdpa_utils.py", line 100, in solve_with_sdpa
call([solverexecutable, tmp_dats_filename, tmp_out_filename])
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I can see the the tool did some computation but then gives error. I know this is a
tool specific question but I can see the program is trying to read/write a file which is not present if I am not wrong. But I am unable to find what exactly the problem is. I would really appreciate if I could be pointed in a direction as to check what exactly the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at lines 1325-1326 of /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py you'll see

```
child_exception = pickle.loads(data)
raise child_exception
```

so it seems like you're trying to unpickle a file that doesn't exist. If that doesn't clear things up for you, I suggest going back up the stack trace, looking at the lines cited, until you find the source of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error is happens in file sdpa_utils.py on line 100, in: `call([solverexecutable, tmp_dats_filename, tmp_out_filename]`

Looks like something wrong with filenames.

To check it, before that line, insert:

`print solverexecutable, tmp_dats_filename, tmp_out_filename`

You should see corresponding filenames in the output, after that, check if it possible to create\read these files in your system.